# Approximation for Beta distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, approximation, approximation-theory, beta-function

I've heard that, when the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of the [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) approach infinity, the distribution becomes approximately [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). But I have only seen a proof of such fact for the case $\alpha = \beta$.

> Is it true that beta distributions with large parameters are
> approximately normal even when the parameters are not equal? If so,
> how big have the parameters to be for the approximation to be good?

I am willing to use this (or any other approximation that simplifies the calculations) with values $\alpha \ge 100$ and $10^4\alpha \ge \beta \ge 10\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

If I poperly remember, if you have a beta distribution with large values of parameters $(\alpha,\beta)$, it almost equivalent to a normal distibution with parameter
$$\frac{\alpha  }{\alpha +\beta} \sqrt{\frac{\alpha  \beta }{(\alpha +\beta )^2 (\alpha +\beta
   +1)}}$$ I think that this comes from Taylor expansions of the beta distribution probability density function.

Use a mean of $\frac\alpha{\alpha+\beta}$ and a variance of $\frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^{2} (1+\alpha+\beta)}$

Comment: Hi, @ClaudeLeibovici. What I heard was exactly that: that the normal distribution with same mean and same variance is a good approximation for the beta distribution we have. My question is: _how good_ is that approximation? When $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not equal, the beta distribution is not symmetric. I suppose that that impacts the goodness of the approximation...

Comment: @Valentino. This is not my favored area but, if I rpoperly remember, as soon as $(\alpha,\beta)$ are really large, it can be very good (remember that this is an approximation based on of first order Taylor expansion of the beta pdf). Why don't you try and  add a plot in your question ? It would be interesting for other users. Cheers :-)